# Ionic: How to have multiple methods in a module and how to display the result in a template?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm new to ionic/angular. I created a rest API for my custom theme taxonomy in WordPress. I created a provider called ads

```
  retrieveAds() { 
    return this.http.get(this.api_url)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
  retrieveThumbInAds(adId: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.thumb_url + adId )
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Then  in my `home.ts`

```
 ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.adsProvider.retrieveAds().subscribe(results => {
      this.ads = results;


    });

     this.adsProvider.retrieveThumbInAds(this.ads).subscribe(results => {   ---> this is wrong, how to correct it?
      this.thumbs = results;
    }); 
  }
```

Then in my `home.html`

```
<ion-card [@fadeIn]="fade" class="category-card" *ngFor="let item of ads">
    <img src="{{item.shop_thumbnail}}" /> ----> this is wrong
    <ion-icon name="md-heart" (click)="activeLike(item)" [ngClass]="{'activeColor':item.like}" class="like-icon" color="light"></ion-icon>
    <div class="card-title" (click)="goDetailPage(item.detail)" text-uppercase>
      <h4 color="secondary">{{item.title.rendered}}</h4>
      <p color="dark">{{item.price}}</p>
      <p  class="excerpt" [innerHtml]="item.excerpt.rendered">  </p>
    </div>

</ion-card>
```

I have two problems in my code, the first being I don't know how to pass the id to the second method, the second problem is how to iterate the thumbnails in the template since they are a different array? should I combine both arrays into one?

- `retreiveAds` should return an array like this

http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

That one is for posts, mine is for ads, a custom post type I created in Wordpress.

- `retrieveThumbInAd` URL should look like this if I manage to get the `id` successfully

http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/media?per_page=1&order=asc&parent=15

where 15 is the id I got from  `retreiveAds` for example. Then I have to loop through the thumbnails and ads details on homepage

Comment: Hi, If the provided answer has solved your question please consider accepting it.

Comment: @Vikas of course I would, if it solved the problem, I've been so busy last week couldn't even try it. Will test it Tuesday. And I can't forget about it since the client is waiting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mate, you are working with **[`async programming`](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript)**  you cannot pause the execution of the code or make it wait and your subscription will be resolved in future but you cannot predict when.

`retrieveAds()` and `retrieveThumbInAds(this.ads)` are executed parallelly this should not be the case since the latter one depends on the value from the former one which is still executing in the background, what you need to do is invoke it when your subscription is resolved.

About the json response you need to convert into an array. use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
 public response=[];
         ionViewDidLoad() {
            this.adsProvider.retrieveAds().subscribe(results => {
             this.response=[];
      Object.keys(results).map((key)=>{ this.response.push(results[key]) });
             //let id=this.response[0].id//use index to extract desired id
            this.getData(id);

            });
        }
        getData(id)
        {
          this.adsProvider.retrieveThumbInAds(id).subscribe(results => {
              this.thumbs = results;
            });
        }
```

Template

```
<ion-card [@fadeIn]="fade" class="category-card" *ngFor="let item of response">
    <img src="{{item?.shop_thumbnail}}" />
```

Comment: I have a problem with id, to illustrate that https://jokerleb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?per_page=1&order=asc&parent=24328 so the id for this example `24329`. Even if I pass that `let id=this.response[24329].id`, it will be unidentified